# A field or property with the name 'ApproveID' was not found on the selected data source

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

i try to add approve type values in dropdownlist in grdiview

**GridView**

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="ApproveID" DataField="ApproveID"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>


                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" 
                  class="vpb_dropdown">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

**SQL**

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[viewdocid]
as
select dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID,dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName,dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile,dbo.DocType.DocType,dbo.Department.DepType
from dbo.DocumentInfo left join dbo.DocType on dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID left join  
dbo.Department on dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID
```

**C#**

```
 protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            //Find the DropDownList in the Row
            DropDownList ddlvalue = (e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList4") as 
             DropDownList);
           ddlvalue .DataSource = GetData("SELECT ApproveID,ApproveType FROM 
            ApproveType");
            ddlvalue .DataTextField = "ApproveType";
           ddlvalue .DataValueField = "ApproveID";
           ddlvalue .DataBind();

            //Add Default Item in the DropDownList
            ddlvalue.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please select"));

            //Select the Country of Customer in DropDownList
            //string country = (e.Row.FindControl("lblCountry") as Label).Text;
            //ddlvalue.Items.FindByValue(country).Selected = true;
        }
    }
```

i add this code in page load

```
            GrdFileApprove.DataSource = dd.gdocid();
            GrdFileApprove.DataBind();
```

where as there is no approveid column in documents table this is only in approval table .
and i try to show approve.reject and pending in dropdownlist in gridview

when i debug the code it show me error in page load code..

```
A field or property with the name 'ApproveID' was not found on the selected data source.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data source that you are binding to the grid view does not contain the column Arrpove type .so obviously you will get that error.

you need to fetch that `Approve id` by using joins between the tables.

A grid view can hold only one result set at at time

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[viewdocid]
as
select A.ApproveID,A.ApproveType dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID,dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName,dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile,dbo.DocType.DocType,dbo.Department.DepType
from dbo.DocumentInfo left join dbo.DocType on dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID left join  
dbo.Department on dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID
left join dbo.ApproveType A on dbo.DocumentInfo.DocID=A.Approvetype
```

hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `ApproveID` column to be present in resulting set. That is, include the column in `SELECT`. If it is in table being joined, you need to do something like this:

```
select [JoinedTable].[Column] AS ApproveID ...
```

Comment: i add this in sp which i mentioed abovee r i create new one?

Comment: you can add it to existing one

Comment: can you tell what is the common column for both the tables?

Comment: is this right?select  DocumentInfo.DocID,dbo.DocumentInfo.DocName,dbo.DocumentInfo.Uploadfile,dbo.DocType.DocType,dbo.Department.DepType ,dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType as ApproveID
from dbo.DocumentInfo left join dbo.DocType on dbo.DocumentInfo.DocTypeID=dbo.DocType.DocTypeID left join  
dbo.Department on dbo.DocumentInfo.DepID=dbo.Department.DepID

Comment: from stored proc it seems it is DepID

Comment: it shows me error (The multi-part identifier "dbo.ApproveType.ApproveType" could not be bound.)

Comment: I don't know the schema, but I think you're not joining ApproveType table, you need to join it as well. Basically you need to have all tables joined first, and then use their columns in select.

Comment: where as ApproveType is table name and also approvetype is column name

Comment: You are not joining the table Approve type..so you will get that error for sure

Comment: can you try below answer?

Comment: Are you having ApproveType in any of doucmentinfo or document tables?

Comment: there is a separte approval table columns are userid,docid,approvetype